# How do I pass a quote that has a space at the end as an argument in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Say I have a shell script at `~/script.sh`:

```
TEST="$1 $2"

echo $TEST
```

And I run it with `bash ~/script.sh "he " "he"`,

The output of the command will be `he he`, but I expected it to be `he  he` because the first argument, which is quote, has a space as the last character of the quote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) In short: `echo "$TEST"`.

Comment: Even better with `printf '%s\n' "$TEST"` as `echo` may modify the contents of the string under some circumstances (like interpreting `\n` as "newline").